# Assigned methods as async Task<t> in c#

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, task

Hello i have a question:An assigned as async Task method will automatically create a new Task and then will run the code inside the method into the new task that has just been created?For example lets just say that i have a post method in a webapi2 like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Menu m)
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(""))
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into Menu (Description,LanguageId,IsActive) values (@Description,@LanguageId,@IsActive) ", con))
    {
        try
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                await con.OpenAsync();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", m.Description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LanguageId", m.LanguageId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", m.IsActive);
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,ex);
        }
        finally
        {
           await  con.CloseAsync();
        }
        return Ok("Inserted Succesfully");
    }
}
```

i will call this method as awaitable using an HttpClient in my application.Should i use

```
Task.Run( () =>
{
    //database code
});
```

to start the task inside the post method or as soon as the method is assigned as Task will start the task automatically?I just want to understand better the asynchronous methods. Thanks!

Comment: HttpClient and the implementation on the server have no relation to each other. Otherwise all client side calls would have to know if the end point they were calling was async. If you do not understand async/await or Tasks there are plenty of articles out there, do a google search and do a little reading. Also you do not need the finally block, the `using` statement will close/dispose the connection.

Comment: On the client side just do something like `await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync ... `. No need to wrap that in a `Task.Run`

Comment: i know that.My question was about the webapi2 side.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Should i use `Task.Run` to start the task inside the post method or as soon as the method is assigned as Task will start the task automatically?

In an `async` method, the `async` keyword controls creating the Task object for you. You do not need to create another one.